# Appcenter pipeline was working fine, but now not building

Tags: visual-studio-app-center, visual-studio-app-center-distribute

My pipeline on appcenter was working fine.
Now I tried to do a push, but is failing with:

```
##[command]git fetch --tags --prune --progress --no-recurse-submodules origin
remote: Invalid username or password
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://***:***@bitbucket.org/company/react-native-proj.git/'
##[error]Git fetch failed with exit code: 128
```

how to fix this?
I have checked and says I have to check for disabled web hooks
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/troubleshooting/code-repos#im-connected-to-bitbucket-and-my-builds-fail-with-git-error

but I have no "disabled" web hooks on bitbucket?

How to fix it? what was the cause?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was an internal bug on appcenter.
After a couple of days chatting with the customer support, it is resolved.
The problem was fixed temporarily by disabling distribution, and just doing build. Then doing the distribution manually...

Comment: Ok so I just try your solution, thanks. However, I don't get it, it `clones` from VSTS but distribute on `App Store Connect`, so why disabling the distribution fix the clone from VSTS?

Answer (score 7):

For anyone having the same issue between App Center and your Devops repo, simply resave your build configuration on App Center and the issue should correct itself.

Answer (score 4):

Taking the @ManuelBetancurt's comment.

You need to disable distribution option and build.
Then you can enable option and build, it will work again.

[image: Distribution build option]

Comment: this was the solution for me

Answer (score 3):

For anyone having the same issue between App Center and your Devops repo, simply resave your build configuration on App Center and the issue should correct itself.

It helps for 3-4 hours and then this situation again. Fix with distribution button will help

Comment: Oh my gosh. This "resave your build configuration" fix rescued me from a nightmare. Thank you, @Yevhen Lv